# NullPointerException at WSO2-IS v4.0.0m9 and OAuth 2.0 playground

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, oauth2-playground, wso2-identity-server

OAuth 2.0 playground (the playground) is an OAuth client sample app for WSO2 Identity Server (the WSO2-IS). I can execute playground with WSO2-IS v4.0.0m3, but it's crashed with WSO2-IS v4.0.0m9 (the exception message as the following). Is playground already updated for IS v4.0.0m9? How to update/fix playground sample?

--- HTTP500 ---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.ui.client.OAuth2ServiceClient._validateClient(OAuth2ServiceClient.java:113)
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.ui.client.OAuth2ServiceClient.validateClient(OAuth2ServiceClient.java:107)
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.ui.endpoints.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.validateClient(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:171)
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.ui.endpoints.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.handleOAuthAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:106)
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.ui.endpoints.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.service(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:70)
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-425. Rajika

Comment: Hi, I am trying IS v4.0.0-m9-alpha * AS v4.1.2. I got a new Exception when I click "Get Photos" button at playground sample : org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://dto.oauth2.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd}jwt